# javascript is not loading dynamically in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am trying to load the js dynamically using the following code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function loadjsfile(filename, filetype){
    if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
    }
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

var hour = new Date().getHours(); 
loadjsfile("http://my.domain/js/util.js?v="+hour, "js");

</script>
```

*Here i am trying to load the js on every hour. But the js is not loading on the refresh action. It is working fine with the firefox and Internet Explorer.*

Comment: You are calling loadjscssfile which is not defined, did you mean loadjsfile? Edit: loadjsfile loads javascript files correctly, tested in Chrome. What problem did you encounter?

Comment: Are you testing directly from file or on a web server/localhost? Because Chrome limit some async actions while you test without http: protocol.

Comment: @RobertoLonardi me? I did test both from a file and from a local apache server. Both work correctly: I used a script in the same path that only has `console.log("loaded");` and It appears in the console, also I can see the script in the Network tab and in the Elements tree. Edit: Tested loading jquery from cdn, it works too.

Comment: @Theraot No I'm asking to him, I thought it could be Chrome that disable async call from file:// paths, but this doesn't seems the case if you tested and it works. Anyway yes the method name is wrong as you mentioned above.

Comment: @RobertoLonardi the method name is mistyped while posting the question.i have again tested and same problem is occuring.  I am testing from the local host. The js file is not loading when i click on the refresh button of the google chorme for the first time. My chrome browser is Version 53.0.2785.143 m.

Comment: @Theraot my problem now reduced to this. i have loaded the util.js using above code. In this util.js, there are some constants are defined. Now after that i am loading another next.js which is using the constants defined in util.js. Now next.js is not getting the constants which is defined in util.js on refresh button action.

Comment: @user6139700 that a different problem. I would suggest a different question. Regardless, how do you do the declarations? I have tried declaring variables in a script with `var x = 123;` and reading them in another with `console.log(x);` and it works when loaded in order with your code. You must be doing something different.